# Bootstrap 3.x navbar links lead nowhere when bootstrap.js is included

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've been trying to get the responsive navbar in Bootstrap 3.2 to work with my site and the weird thing is that it works perfectly, so long as I do not include the bootstrap.js file. Seeing as the "responsive" part of the navbar (a.k.a the hamburger-button) is dependent on this file being present when the navbar collapses I would like to get it to work even with this pesky file present. I've tried putting it both inside the head-tag and just above the closing body-tag but it makes no difference (And I've also made sure to always place it beneath jquery.) Here's my navbar:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- RAD 1: Navigation -->
        <header class="row">    
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                      
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Optalux</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">                
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="om-optalux.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Om Optalux</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="om-optalux.html#personlig-ogonkirurgi">Personlig Ögonkirurgi</a></li>
                                <li><a href="om-optalux.html#medicinsk-verksamhetschef">Medicinsk Verksamhetschef</a></li>
                                <li><a href="om-optalux.html#lediga-tjanster">Lediga Tjänster</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                           
                    </ul>
                </div>              
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

To repeat: The navbar works fine in default-mode (not collapsed) so long as I do not include the bootstrap.js file but without it the responsive mode is pretty useless.
I would greatly appreciate any help because this is driving me nuts.

Comment: When you use any web developer tools to see if the .js is being called, is the bootstrap.js file actually being loaded?

Comment: The thing is that with the bootstrap.js file included I can actually click the "hamburger"-button and unfold the menu (by this I take it that it's actually being loaded) but if I leave it out the button won't work at all. But if I include the bootstrap.js file, clicking on any menu-items (links) won't take me to the other pages.

Comment: I think if you don't use the hamburger button, you should remove the div that collapses the menu.

Comment: I like the hamburger button so I'll keep on trying to get it to work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `class` and `data-toggle` attributes from your dropdown-menu items:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="om-optalux.html#personlig-ogonkirurgi">Personlig Ögonkirurgi</a></li>
  <li><a href="om-optalux.html#medicinsk-verksamhetschef">Medicinsk Verksamhetschef</a></li>
  <li><a href="om-optalux.html#lediga-tjanster">Lediga Tjänster</a></li>
</ul>
```

The Bootstrap Dropdown plugin sees the `data-toggle='dropdown'` markup and tries to convert those items into dropdowns. It is intercepting (and preventing the default behavior) whenever you click on the links.

Comment: That is definately something that I should have caught but unfortunately it did not resolve the issue. Thanks for pointing it out though! Edit: I edited my original post to reflect that that this is not what's causing the problem.

Comment: Ok I got it working and you were right - It was the class and data-toggle that was messing things up. Not only did I have to remove these from the li-tags but I also had to remove them from the a-tag above which is odd because that's how the navbar-example on bootstrap's own page is written. Anyways, thanks for the help!